# Concat strings in nested json with other string in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying an aggregation in MongoDB in order to convert:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "acronym": "MC",
    "tickers": [
      {
        "name": "Sensor1-front",
        "symbol": "s1f"
      },
      {
        "name": "Sensor1-back",
        "symbol": "s1b"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

into something like this:

```
['s1f.MC','s1b.MC']
```

Where each `symbol` in `tickers` is concat to `acronym`.

I am trying it with `$concat`, `$group`, etc but I am not going anywhere.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure but may be you could try `$set`, `$concat` and `$merge`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use reduce

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      newField: {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$tickers",
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": {
            "$concatArrays": [
              [
                {
                  "$concat": [
                    "$$this.symbol",
                    ".",
                    "$acronym"
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Pnd6_OCL4DP)**

Comment: You can also use [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) as follows: https://mongoplayground.net/p/l5J7U5ddBS8

Comment: Yeah, using `$map` is also a good solution!